# Dynamically passing varying arguments to a predefined function

Tags: python

I've been looking for a while and I haven't found anything similar to what I'm looking for. I want to be able to pass varying parameters to a function that is already defined in an API.

For example, I get a list of args from my CLI, some of which are optional. I want to pass all the given args to this function. The function in the API is accepting the args with **kwargs (and an additional arg that is required).

Right now I have a dictionary of the args and I somehow need to pass them to the function in the form of `func_name(param1=val1, param2=val2)` and so on. I have no idea how to convert my dictionary (that looks like `{'param1':val1, 'param2':val2}`) into the format for the function.

There must be a nicer way to do this than to write out a separate if statement for every possible scenario. Thanks in advance for your help!

**TL;DR:**
**How can I pass values from a dictionary like `{'param1':val1, 'param2':val2}` into a function call like `func_name(param1=val1, param2=val2)`?**

Comment: You can unpack your dict: `func_name(**my_dict)`.

Comment: @DelganThank you! I knew there had to be something simple, but I couldn't find it. Thanks so much.